# Json Desearialization C# URL

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, special-characters

I have this problem:

I'm consuming a JSON from backend which contains this:

```
  "results": [{
    "id": "3bc895f3-2439-4db8-8015-ddf82841c26b",
    "code": "test",
    "urlImagePromotion": "http://mmblob.blob.core.windows.net/img/img_02a479e2_4b41_4c34_bb34_afda77dbad9e.png"
}]
```

When i deserialize to my class, the attribute urlImagePromotion is allways null.

```
var response =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultiResultResponse<TestClass>>(result);

public class MultiResultResponse<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

My TestClass:

```
public Guid? Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("urlImagePromotion")]
public string UrlImagePromotion { get; set; }
```

Maybe its allways null because that string has special characters?

How can i get the correct value?

Thanks you

Comment: What is MultiResultResponse<T>? Is you able to reproduce your issue here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Updated the post with MultiResultResponse. In MultiResultResponse.Results i have that json

Comment: How are you deserializing? Please provide complete code.

Comment: you're not posting the complete code, the JSON you posted do not match  your class defition, I suppose that piece should be inside an array and is part of a bigger json, again try to isolate and simulate your issue using https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: I simply the Json and class